# Codomain that function is surjective.

Tags: analysis

If A is the set of all real numbers and the function  $f: A \rightarrow \mathbb{R} $ is defined by $f(x)=x^2-5x+5$, how can I determine the largest codomain that the function is surjective (that is, maps to every real number).

Comment: Complete the square. What do you know about all numbers of the form $y^2$ for $y\in\Bbb R$?

Comment: What is the problem here -- dealing with all the fancy terminology, or finding the range of a quadratic function?

Answer (score 0):

$$f'(x)=2x-5$$

$f $ attains its minimum at $x=5/2.$

$f (5/2)=-5/4$

thus $f $ is a surjection from $A $ to $B=[-5/4,+\infty) $.

Let $y\in B $.
is there $$x\in A \;\;:\; x^2-5x+5=y $$

$$\Delta=25-20+4y $$
if $y\ge -5/4,  x $ exists.